# moise and downs tests

Tags: geometry

I am teaching a course on Geometry and have to use the text book by Moise and Downs.  I used this text book myself when I learned Geometry long ago and really like it.  I am wondering if anyone knows if there is any kind of resource book that goes along with the Moise and Downs text that would include sample tests and quizzes.

Comment: You may want to try asking this question on [https://matheducators.stackexchange.com](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).